# selectBooleanCheckBox does not work seperatly in p:dialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have button that when I click on it, the dialog appear and in that dialog , I have `p:selectBooleanCheckBox` and `h:outputlable`.

The first problem is  when p:dialog appear I can not choose `p:selectBooleanCheckBox` separately. It means that when I click on one of them, all of `p:selectBooleanCheckBox`  choose.

The second problem is when I click on `p:commandButton` in dialog , the `actionListener` work but it dos not disappaer and it shows permanently. I think the problem cause by Ajax. could you please tell me how can I fix this problem?

```
              <h:panelGrid>
                <p:dialog  appendToBody="true"  header="Selected Values" modal="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" widgetVar="dlg">  
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="display">  
                            <p:dataGrid id="AcceptDataGrid" var="tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo" value="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.filterBusinessRequest()}"
                                        columns="1" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputLabel value="test"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </p:dataGrid>
                        <p:commandButton  id="acceptCommonButton" value="#{inviteRequest_msg.accept}"  
                                          actionListener="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.acceptRequest(tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.id)}" 
                                          update="display" />
                        </h:panelGrid> 


                </p:dialog>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

---

```
            <table style="width: 100%" id="tabell">
                <p:selectOneButton  value="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.filterType}">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{inviteRequest_msg.request}" itemValue="request" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{inviteRequest_msg.archive}" itemValue="archive" />   
                    <f:ajax event="change"  execute="@form" render="@form" />             
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p:panel></p:panel>

                            <p:dataGrid id="requestDataGrid" var="tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo" 
                                        value="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.filterBusinessRequest()}" columns="1" >

                                <p:column>
                                    <div>
                                        <table border="0"  width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <p:graphicImage value="#{tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.partySender_imageUrl}"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <table border="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <h:outputLabel value="#{tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.requestDate}"/>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <h:outputLabel value="#{tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.partySender_fullName}"/>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
```

here is where p:dialog call

```
                                                <td>

                         <p:commandButton  id="acceptCommonButton" value="#{inviteRequest_msg.accept}"
                                                                      onclick="dlg.show()" />
                                                </td>


                                                <td>
                                                    <p:commandButton  id="noNowCommonButton" value="#{inviteRequest_msg.notnow}"  
                                                                      actionListener="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.notNowRequest(tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.id)}" 
                                                                      update="@form" />
                                                </td>
                                                <p:blockUI block="acceptCommonButton" trigger="acceptCommonButton"/>
                                                <p:blockUI block="noNowCommonButton" trigger="acceptCommonButton"/>
                                                <p:blockUI block="acceptCommonButton" trigger="noNowCommonButton"/>
                                                <p:blockUI block="noNowCommonButton" trigger="noNowCommonButton"/>

                                                <td>
                                                    <p:panel>
                                                        <p:ajaxStatus>
                                                            <f:facet name="start">
                                                                <p:graphicImage value="../resources/img/loading.gif"/>
                                                            </f:facet>
                                                            <f:facet name="complete">
                                                                <h:outputLabel value=""/>
                                                            </f:facet>
                                                        </p:ajaxStatus>
                                                    </p:panel>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr/>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataGrid>                   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </p:selectOneButton>

            </table>

    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid>
        <p:dialog  appendToBody="true"  header="Selected Values" modal="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" widgetVar="dlg">  
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="display">  
                    <p:dataGrid id="AcceptDataGrid" var="tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo" value="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.loadPartyRelationShipType()}"
                                columns="1" >
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h:outputLabel value="test"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </p:dataGrid>
                 <p:commandButton  id="acceptCommonButton" value="#{inviteRequest_msg.accept}"  
                                  actionListener="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.acceptRequest(tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.id)}" 
                                  update="display" oncomplete="dlg.hide()"  />

                </h:panelGrid> 

        </p:dialog>
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but it does not disappear and it shows permanently` are you talking about the dialog that stays showed? You have to hide it yourself by calling dlg.hide() at some point.

Comment: @ Alexandre :
thank you.yes, i use "oncomplete="dlg.hide()" and the second problem solved.
but the first problem still alive :(

Comment: So does the `dialog` hides in the end? By the way be careful, if validation fails your dialog will hide anyway as it only wait for the ajax request to complete.

Comment: yes, dialog hides now.
but i can not still select p:selectBooleanCheckBox seperatly.
when i want to select one of them, all of them selected.

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the facelets that triggers the opening of the dialog, plus the parent element that loops (`<p:dataTable`, `<ui:repeat`...) simplified at most

Comment: i add the code and show where i call p:dialog in code!

Comment: I can't see any `dlg.show`, is the call made in the bean? May be in `#{inviteRequestManagedBean.notNowRequest(...)}`?

Comment: @M.rEzAmOjaLlaL , When you are using `appendToBody="true"` your dialog will be taken from its content in the jsf page and will be appended to the body of the generated page

Comment: @Alexandre  :  i edit my code now. you can see dlg.show after "here is where p:dialog call " line

Comment: @Daniel: you mean that i should change it to "false"?
i change it, but the problem still alive ...

Comment: A last thing before I can give you an answer, why isn't `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox` bound to anything (`value` attribute)? It should be bound to something in a backing bean!

Comment: @Alexandre: i just want the <p:selectBooleanCheckbox show, and it is my sample. i don,t want to do anything yet. 
so what is solution? :)

Comment: @Alexandre: how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is a bit scary, I don't get why you've got so much thing in your `<p:selectOneButton` (all the `<tr>`'s) so instead of trying to correct everything as I start to understand what you try to achieve I'll give you a working example.

Sample.java

```
public class Sample implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private boolean checked;

    public Sample() {
    }

    public Sample(String name, boolean checked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for name and checked omitted
}
```

SampleBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SampleBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Sample> samples;

    private Sample currentSample;

    public void prepareEdit(Sample sample) {
        this.currentSample = sample;
    }

    public void edit() {
        // Do what you need to do with sample
        // You can get it with : this.currentSample
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dlg.hide()");
    }

    public List<Sample> getSamples() {
        if (this.samples == null) {
            this.samples = new ArrayList<Sample>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
                this.samples.add(new Sample("Sample n°" + i, (i % 3 == 0)));
            }
        }
        return samples;
    }

    public void setSamples(List<Sample> samples) {
        this.samples = samples;
    }

    public Sample getCurrentSample() {
        return currentSample;
    }

    public void setCurrentSample(Sample currentSample) {
        this.currentSample = currentSample;
    }
}
```

view.xhtml :

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:dataTable value="#{sampleBean.samples}" var="sample">
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{sample.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Checked?">
            <h:outputText value="#{sample.checked}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width: 1px; text-align: center;">
            <p:commandButton value="edit"
                             actionListener="#{sampleBean.prepareEdit(sample)}"
                             update=":dialog"
                             oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dlg" header="Editing">
    <h:form rendered="#{!empty sampleBean.currentSample}">
        <h:outputText value="Current sample is #{sampleBean.currentSample.name}" />
        <br />
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{sampleBean.currentSample.checked}" />
        <br />
        <p style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{sampleBean.edit()}"
                             value="Edit"
                             update="@form :myForm" />
        </p>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

As you can see I'm storing a `currentSample` (`sampleBean` **must** be `@ViewScoped`) which helps me to render a custom dialog with the correct current information.

My last comment from your question about the binding of the `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is important because you can get a custom checkbox value only if it's bound to a different endpoint based on the context (here `currentSample`).

Don't hesitate to comment if something is unclear for you!